# call action method from global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to call action method of controller from Global.asax.cs.

Here is my actionMethod:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<ActionResult> ErrorInsert(int Id, string severity, string description,string details)
  {
        return new EmptyResult();

  }
```

I have to capture the events when IIS shutdown unexpectedly in Global.asax

```
protected void Application_End()
        {
            var s_activityGuid = Guid.NewGuid();

                try
                {

                    System.Web.ApplicationShutdownReason shutReason = System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ShutdownReason;
                    string shutMessage = string.Empty;
                    //var urlHelper = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);
                    var routeData = new RouteData();
                    routeData.Values["controller"] = "ErrorRouting";
                    routeData.Values["action"] = "ErrorInsert";

                    if (shutReason == System.Web.ApplicationShutdownReason.BinDirChangeOrDirectoryRename)
                    {
                        shutMessage = "There is a shut down because of change to the Bin folder or files contained in it.";
                        routeData.Values["Id"] = 1;
                        routeData.Values["severity"] = "Error";
                        routeData.Values["description"] = shutReason;
                        routeData.Values["details"] = shutMessage;
                        IController routeController = new ErrorRoutingController();
                        var rc = new RequestContext(new HttpContextWrapper(Context), routeData);
                        diagnosticController.Execute(rc);
                        //Response.Redirect(urlHelper.Action("ErrorInsert", "ErrorRouting",new { Id=1200, severity= "Error", description= shutReason, details= shutMessage } ));
                    }

                    log.WriteEntry(shutMessage, EventLogEntryType.Error);

                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                }
            }
        }
```

I have tried with Response.Redirect and controller.excute() approaches.

In both cases, I am getting HttpContext as Null and it is failing.

Requirement is it should call the action method mentioned and continue the execution in Application_End() method.

Please let me know how can I do this.

I am not sure why HttpContext is coming null?

Comment: Why does it need to be an action method that records your information?  Why can't it just call a normal method?

Comment: You don't need to call action method actually. But if you want so then give an api call or call to action from C# code. You can call using HttpClient.

Comment: from the action method,I am making an Api call to insert into database.

Comment: What you're asking for is not possible. It looks like you're simply trying to add some error handling, but this is not the right way to do it (which is why you're butting up against a wall). Look into the `httpErrors` config element.

Comment: The intention is to store the errors in db for future reference.

Answer (score 3):

Application_End is application level event it will not execute based on the per Request basis. That is the reason you are getting HttpContext as null because its not tied to request context.